# Basic Question Regarding Expectation of Function

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, economics

I'll quickly setup the question. This is from a microeconomics text covering the contractual relationship between the owner of a store and the manager, who will operate the store. 
$$
 \pi_g = e + \epsilon
$$
$ \pi_g $ - Gross Profit
$ e $ - The manager's effort
$ \epsilon $ - Random Error

Taking the abstraction one step further,
$$
\pi_{n}=\pi_{g}-s,
$$

where, $ \pi_n $ represents Net Profit, s is the manager's salary.

It's assumed error will be mean zero and variance $ \sigma^2 $ such that, the owner will maximize the expected value of his net profit:

$$
E\left(\pi_{n}\right)=E(e+\varepsilon-s)=e-E(s)
$$

Question: Mathematically speaking, how does the function simplify to e instead of expectation of e?

Comment: mathematically there's nothing you can do to omit the expectation, it could be the case that in the formulation of the problem the principal (owner) fixes an incentive compatibility constraint in order to force the manager to exert a given level of effort, and hence it's not longer a random variable. You should provide some more context

Comment: or it could be the case that the owner takes the behaviour of the manager as given and hence the expectation taken w.r.t the random error, not respect to the manager's behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mathematically speaking, how does the function simplify to e instead
>   of expectation of e?

This is the nature of expectation. $e$ is a constant. And the expectation of an constant is just the constant itself.

More generally. $\mathbb E(X+c)=\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(c)$, where X is a random variable with expectation $\mu$.  Here *linearity of expectation* has been applied. Then we use the the fact, that  the expectation of an constant is the constant itself.

$$\mathbb E(X)+\mathbb E(c)=E(X)+0=\mu+0=\mu$$

In your case we have

$$E\left(\pi_{n}\right)=\mathbb E(e+\varepsilon-s)=\mathbb E(e)+\mathbb E(\varepsilon)-\mathbb E(s)=e+0-\mathbb E(s)=e-\mathbb E(s)$$

You probably interested in the variance. The constant has no impact on the variance of the sum. $$Var(e+\varepsilon-s)=Var(\varepsilon-s)$$

It seems that $\varepsilon$ and $s$ are independent. That means $Cov(\varepsilon,s)=0$. Therefore $$Var(\varepsilon-s)=Var(\varepsilon)+Var(s)=\sigma^2+Var(s)$$